# Como usar a notação de potencia em HTML?

Tags: html

Como formatar 2 números em potência?

Exemplo:

```
2, 2 = 2²
3, 2 = 3²
5, 3 = 5³
6, 2 = 6²
```

Comment: Você fala de **calcular** uma potência ou de **formatar** um número como potência?

Comment: formatar um numero como potencia!!!

Comment: formatar os números não é um problema de javascript. é um problema de HTML

Comment: como formatar pelo html em potencia ? lembrando que eu tenho esse numero por exemplo "2,2" e preciso que vire "2²"

Comment: Esse seu edit com a segunda pergunta muda a pergunta. Vou voltar a trás, se não concordar diga, ou faça nova pergunta...

Comment: fiz uma nova pergunta...mas ficou estranho pois as 2 são bem parecidas...

Answer (score 11):

O elemento HTML `<sup>` pode ser usado para colocar um texto nessa forma:

```
2<sup>3</sup>
```

Vira: 2<sup>3</sup>.

Alternativamente, você pode usar os [caracteres Unicode para *superscript*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) (embora apenas poucos deles sejam suportados):

```
2&#x00B3;
```

2³. Nesse caso seria necessário mapear cada número de `0` a `9` ao seu *code point* correspondente.

Answer (score 5):

Se tem esse valor numa string como colocou pode fazer assim:

```
var x = '2,5';
var partes = x.split(',');
var htmlString = partes[0] + '<sup>' + partes[1] + '</sup>';
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/rbcg7hxL/